# Prevent text from being erased when it is highlighted in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

In a contenteditable `h1` tag I am trying to have an event fire when text is highlighted and you press enter WITHOUT the text being erased and a a new line being inserted.

I'm trying to achieve this with the following javascript:

```
document.bind('keyup', function(ev) {
  if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
    //do something instead of erasing text
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

But the highlighted text still seems to have focus, erases and inserts a new line when I press enter.

Is there anyway to prevent this when text is highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyup` event is too late. Do it using the `keydown` event instead. Also, `document.bind` is not the correct syntax and will throw an error. You need [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
    //do something instead of erasing text
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```